# Error 1064 in SQL Code

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I used the phpMyAdmin form to create a table, i.e. I filled in the fields and it generated the code. The code generated doesn't work, but I can't find the error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
```

userEmail VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (' at line 14

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
userID INT( 9 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
userName VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
userPwd VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
userTitle VARCHAR( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
fName VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
lName VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
address VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
dateOfBirth VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL ,
userJob VARCHAR( 15 ) NULL ,
regDate VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
accType CHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'F',
regCode VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
isActivated BOOL( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
userEmail VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  userID ) ,
UNIQUE (userName ,userEmail)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

mysql ver 5.1    php ver 5.2.*

Comment: You could also use `BIT(1)` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-type.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 
`isActivated BOOL( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',`

to

`isActivated BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',`

you can read about it more : [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> M indicates the maximum display width for integer types

Bool does not have this so you can't specify width. it's always 1

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use BOOL(1)
Try the following (i just replaced BOOL(1) with BOOL)
BOOL and BOOLEAN are synonyms for TINYINT(1).

```
CREATE TABLE members (
userID INT( 9 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
userName VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
userPwd VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,
userTitle VARCHAR( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
fName VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
lName VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
address VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
dateOfBirth VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL ,
userJob VARCHAR( 15 ) NULL ,
regDate VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
accType CHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'F',
regCode VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
isActivated BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
userEmail VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  userID ) ,
UNIQUE (userName ,userEmail)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Comment: changed line 16 to line 14. Thx for the help. Also The double parameters for unique seems to be working.